# How do I install iptables-dev on Ubuntu 20.04 with apt?

Tags: apt, compiling, iptables, aptitude

I tried the following:

`sudo apt install iptables-dev`

But get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package iptables-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libxtables-dev libip6tc-dev libip4tc-dev

E: Package 'iptables-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I get that iptables is deprecated, however I need this package as I am trying to run the following command that requires it:

```
# sudo apt-get build-dep strongswan
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:strongswan : Depends: iptables-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is this not an option anymore? Must I compile from source?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, well more so a workaround.
I deployed a Ubuntu 18.04 separate VM.
Then I did

`sudo apt download iptables-dev`

This gave me `iptables-dev_1.6.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb`. I then scp'ed the file to the 20.04 server, and installed with

`sudo dpkg -i iptables-dev_1.6.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb`